# 8-byte number in reported property of Azure IoT hub device twin automatically converted to float

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I want to report to report an exact 8-byte number as reported property via the device twin to the IoT Hub. However, when viewing the values in the azure portal, I only see floating point numbers in scientific format.
The Azure doc on the page here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins says: All values in JSON objects can be of the following JSON types: boolean, number, string, object.

When I convert the numbers from Azure portal back, e.g. with python:
print(format(int(float("7.26238597903829E+16")), "016x"))
the number is incorrect, due to imprecise float format, I guess.

I read here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp that JSON numbers can be either integers or floating point numbers. Hence I assume int numbers should not be a problem.

The struct declaration for the serializer in my C-code looks like this:

```
DECLARE_STRUCT(NodeType,
int64_t, addr,
uint8_t, status
);
```

Is it possible to retrieve EXACT 64 bit numbers from a device twin reported property?

EDIT: for reproducing the issue, I created a new device on the IoT hub with device id "car". I downloaded the current azure-iot-c-sdk and modified the devicetwin_simplesample from the serializer samples. Here is the diff:

```
diff --git a/serializer/samples/devicetwin_simplesample/devicetwin_simplesample.c b/serializer/samples/devicetwin_simplesample/devicetwin_simplesample.c
index 7da717c..4f9e28d 100644
--- a/serializer/samples/devicetwin_simplesample/devicetwin_simplesample.c
+++ b/serializer/samples/devicetwin_simplesample/devicetwin_simplesample.c
@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@

 /*String containing Hostname, Device Id & Device Key in the format:             */
 /*  "HostName=<host_name>;DeviceId=<device_id>;SharedAccessKey=<device_key>"    */
-static const char* connectionString = "HostName=...";
+static const char* connectionString = "HostName=XXX.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=car;SharedAccessKey=XXXX";

 // Define the Model - it is a car.
 BEGIN_NAMESPACE(Contoso);
@@ -31,7 +31,7 @@ DECLARE_STRUCT(Geo,
 );

 DECLARE_MODEL(CarState,
-    WITH_REPORTED_PROPERTY(int32_t, softwareVersion),
+    WITH_REPORTED_PROPERTY(int64_t, softwareVersion),
     WITH_REPORTED_PROPERTY(uint8_t, reported_maxSpeed),
     WITH_REPORTED_PROPERTY(ascii_char_ptr, vanityPlate)
 );
@@ -125,7 +125,7 @@ void device_twin_simple_sample_run(void)
                     car->maker.style = "sedan";
                     car->maker.year = 2014;
                     car->state.reported_maxSpeed = 100;
-                    car->state.softwareVersion = 1;
+                    car->state.softwareVersion = 0x0102030405060708;
                     car->state.vanityPlate = "1I1";

                     /*sending the values to IoTHub*/
```

After I start this sample, I get a flaoting point number for the SW version number in the device twin (partially shown here) in my Azure portal:

```
{
  "deviceId": "car",
  "etag": "AAAAAAAAAAE=",
  "properties": {
    "desired": {
      "$metadata": {
        "$lastUpdated": "2017-08-14T14:03:24.5887488Z"
      },
      "$version": 1
    },
    "reported": {
      "state": {
        "softwareVersion": 72623859790382848.0,
        "reported_maxSpeed": 100,
        "vanityPlate": "1I1"
      },
      ...
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample code that how you updated reported property? I test with C# and the 8-byte number doesn't be automatically converted. It is the same in the azure portal with in my code.

Comment: Please find my edits with a diff above. I'm using the C SDK. This test was done with Ubuntu 16.04 and their gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue caused by representing your int64 value with JSON type: number and number type is double- precision floating-point format in JavaScript.

For [double- precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

- Sign bit: 1 bit
- Exponent: 11 bits
- Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

So the max integer it can represent is 2^52, for Hexadecimal is  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF, for decimal is 4503599627370495.

Because your `softwareVersion` value extends the range it can represent so it cut redundant bits, then you get the wrong value.

For your case, you can split the 64-bit value into two 32-bit values at the sender side and recombine two 32-bit values to a 64-bit value at the receiver side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's a bit misleading though that `int64_t` is possible in the model declaration. Anyway, now I know how to get around this :)